# Loading CSV and retrieving from it at the same time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

I loaded a csv file, and Now I want to retrieve the record of whose last_name is GUINESS.

I am new to cypher. and I don't know what's happening.

This is my code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:C:/CSV/actor.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Actor {actor_id: row.actor_id, first_name: row.first_name, last_name: row.last_name, last_update: row.last_update})
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.last_name='GUINESS'
RETURN n;
```

P.S: There is actually a record in the actor.csv where last_name=GUINESS.

Please help me out, I've got an assignment.

Comment: it should work, but why don't you do it in a separate query? are you sure it's not GUINNeSS with two N's?

Answer (score 2):

Split it up into multiple steps:

The first two are executed once, the query you can do as often as you like.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/CSV/actor.csv" AS row 
CREATE (:Actor {actor_id: row.actor_id, first_name: row.first_name, last_name: row.last_name, last_update: row.last_update});

create index on :Actor(last_name);

MATCH (n:Actor) WHERE n.last_name='GUINNESS' RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the match of the `last_name = GUINNESS` with the load operation. I would be tempted to wait until after the data was loaded. That might have the effect of loading nothing at all if the database is empty already.

I would set your files setting to this though `file:///C:/CSV/actor.csv`.